# MobileFirst Platform JavaScript adapter can't get the parameters through WLResourceRequest

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using mobilefirst platform v7,  and I send post request using the  WLResourceRequest/sendFormParameters api, however, I can't get the submitted parameters from js adapter side...

belows are sample code:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/businessAdapter/flightsearch", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var params={
        "flightNum":'mu8899',
        "departCity":'SHA',
        "destCity" :'PEK'
};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(params).then(
        callSuccess,
        callFailure
);
```

js adapter code:

```
function flightsearch(params) {
   WL.Logger.info("get params "+params);


    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'restapi/api/flightsearch',
        body :{
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            content:params
        },
        headers: {"Accept":"application\/json"} 
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax you used is fine for Java adapters.

However, in the case of JavaScript adapters, procedure parameters are handled differently.

First, your adapter procedure should define the parameters that it expects:

```
function flightsearch(flightNum, departCity, destCity) {
///
}
```

Secondly, this procedure will be triggered using an HTTP `GET` or `POST` with a single parameter called `params` which needs to contain an array, representing all the procedure parameters in the correct order:

```
params:["mu8899","SHA","PEK"]
```

Now using JavaScript, this would translate to:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/businessAdapter/flightsearch", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var params=[
        'mu8899',
        'SHA',
        'PEK'
];
var newParams = {'params' : JSON.stringify(params)};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(newParams).then(
        callSuccess,
        callFailure
);
```

As you can see, we first build the JSON array (note, **array** not object) in the correct order, then we convert it to String and send it to the adapter with the parameter name '`params`'.