# Adapter not getting called in IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.0

Tags: mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to call javascript adapter procedure using `WLResourceRequest`. But it is not getting called.

Client Code Snippet:

```
var url = "/adapters/AdapterNew/getFeed";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
resourceRequest.send().then(app.onSuccess, app.onFailure);
```

Server Code Snippet:

```
function getFeed(tag) {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : getPath(tag)
    };
    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

It is not giving any error.
Please let me know the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the code in your onSuccess and onFailure functions ? Do either of them get called ?

Comment: What does your client side logs say? What about server side?

Comment: Hi,
Only alert(“Msg”) added in onSuccess and onFailure methods. Neither onSuccess nor onFailure get called. I have followed steps as per https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/server-side-log-collection/javascript-adapter/  for enabling of server logs. Still I cannot see logs in Analytics Console.
Thanks,

Comment: 1) Wait for 30 seconds to see if the call times out. 2) Check your MFP server logs - not Analytics console 3) Use Wireshark or tcpdump to see the network traffic

Comment: 1) It doesn't timeout.
2) I have checked server log at path ..\MobileFirst-8.0.0.0\mfp-server\usr\servers\mfp\logs\messages.txt
To display server log, I have used code snippet that includes MFP.Logger.debug():
function getFeed(tag) {
 MFP.Logger.debug("This is a debug message");
 var input = {
     method : 'get',
     returnedContentType : 'xml',
     path : getPath(tag)
 };
 return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

Here, messages.txt doesn't update as per MFP.Logger.debug() statement.
It seems that getFeed(tag) method is not getting called. 
Please suggest solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Following is the way I have created adapter in MobileFirst 8.0:
- Created MobileFirst Cordova project using Eclipse Thym.
- Created a new adapter using mfpdev and imported into same Eclipse workspace.
- Preview Cordova project and deploy adapter to MobileFirst console. Both are separate independent project in eclipse.

Please let me know if I have to enable some settings.

Thanks,

Comment: Provide a recreate sample

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the discussion here.

[MobileFirst Platform JavaScript adapter can't get the parameters through WLResourceRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044473/mobilefirst-platform-javascript-adapter-cant-get-the-parameters-through-wlresou)

Basically for javascript parameters are handled differently and the explanation given in the above should help here as well.